# How to copy paste chords into a part in Musescore?

Tags: chords, musescore

One very common situation when I use Musescore is that I have created a tuba part with chords, and I want to copy only the chords into another part that also contains notes.

I want to transform this

[image]

to this

[image]

Doing this manually is very time consuming. Do you know a quick way to do it? I realize that handling the pause in third bar for the trumpet may be a bit overkill, but I'm happy for any solution that at least somewhat makes this automatic.

I posted my current method as an answer. What I don't like about this solution is partly because I need to click on every single chord, but also that it does not fix the pause. The latter one is not very important, but the first one still makes it quite tedious if you want to do this for a whole song with 20 parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R-click a Chord Symbol in the Tuba stave.

Select - All Similar Elements in Same Stave.

Press Ctrl-C  to copy them to the clipboard.

Select the first object in another stave.  Paste.  Repeat for the rest of the staves.

That's all.   Transposition for Bb Trumpet will be automatic.  It's usual to show everyone the entire chord sequence even if there are rests.

Comment: I cannot understand I did not think about that myself...